# During a VS Code Live Share session, how can I make a participant's Python "Run File in Terminal" button run a host's file on the participant machine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-liveshare, vscode-liveshare

I am using Visual Studio Code Live Share to teach a student programming in Python. When they click the run button they get an error because vscode seems to be trying to run python from the command line, using my file (which doesn't exist on their file system).

I know we can have a shared terminal, but they do not know how to use terminal commands yet. Is there a way I can configure their run button to run the code locally, or alternatively, to run the code in our shared terminal by default?

Comment: were able to figure this out ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.