# VSCode Live Share: How can a participant run the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

Me and a friend using VSCode and Live Share to programm some python scripts together. The only problem ist that he cant run the code. If he press F5 (His default button to run code) he get the error "command 'python.execInTerminal-icon' not found".
Any solutions that he can run it too and see the working programm?

Comment: dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60489768/11107541